# how to install android framework on computer without using VM

Tags: android, frameworks, virtual-machine

I want to install android framework on computer so i can send it command remotely to execute
and get reply from it. Is there any way to do this?, plz. help me out waiting for reply...

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Android SDK [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) which includes the Android Application Framework for Windows, OS X and Linux.